# I can't seem to insert into mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, insert

I'm trying to connect to mongodb, and then insert a document called `data`, I can see on my cluster that I connect, but no data gets inserted. I don't get any errors either. Here's my code:

```js
const {MongoClient, ServerApiVersion} = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>-@bussar.v5r4pfd.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });

MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true }).then((client) => {
    let db = client.db("Bussar");
});

function createbus(data) {
    client.connect(err => {
        const bussar = db.collection("busscoll");
        bussar.insertOne(data);
        client.close()
    });
}
```

I do have both user and password filled out in my uri.

**EDIT**
Alright, so I've updated my code, and I belive it works better than before. Although it still doesn't insert anything, I added some checkpoints, and I **only** get to the first one. Code:

```js
const {MongoClient, ServerApiVersion} = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>-@Bussar.v5r4pfd.mongodb.net/bussdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });

function createbus(data) {
    console.log("checkpoint 1");
    try {
        client.connect(err => {
            console.log("checkpoint 2");
            const db = client.db("bussdb")
            console.log("checkpoint 3");
            const bussar = db.collection("busscoll");
            console.log("checkpoint 4");
            bussar.insertOne(data, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                console.log(result);
                client.close();
            });
            console.log("checkpoint 5");
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    } finally {
        client.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you didn't mention the collection name of your MongoDB database in your URI.

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@bussar.v5r4pfd.mongodb.net/Bussar?retryWrites=true&w=majority/your_collection_name";
```

Comment: What's my collection name? `bussdb.busscoll`, or just `busscoll`?

Comment: just busscoll @Sten

Comment: Yeah, managed to find that out. xd

Answer (score 0):

Hi there you did not insert your db name:

Add your db at the `<dbname>` place after `mongodb.net/`

```
"mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>-@bussar.v5r4pfd.mongodb.net/<DbName>?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```